# Where can I download a full .pdf copy of the Cisco Internetworking Technology Handbook, rather than just the chapters?

Tags: cisco

Cisco publish the [Internetworking Technology Handbook](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/internetworking/technology/handbook/Intro-to-Internet.html) on their website but they only provide the individual chapters in pdf. Is there a .pdf of the entire thing available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually you can just run:

```
wget -r --no-parent -A "*.pdf" http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/internetworking/technology/handbook/ito_doc.html
```

Which will grab just the PDFs.

You can use the GPL2/free basic version of [pdfsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/?page_id=10) (PDF Split and Merge) or ghostscript (gs) if on Linux/command line (apt-get install ghostscript if on Ubuntu/Debian, etc. likely there's an RPM or you can compile from source as well).

Edit:

I can't believe I just did this, but what the hey: here's the entire gs cmd, copy and paste (and I better get the Answer for this):

```
gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=Cisco.Internetworking.Technology.Handbook.pdf Intro-to-Internet.pdf Intro-to-LAN.pdf Intro-to-WAN.pdf Bridging-Basics.pdf Routing-Basics.pdf NM-Basics.pdf Ethernet.pdf FDDI.pdf Token-Ring.pdf Frame-Relay.pdf HSSI.pdf ISDN.pdf PPP.pdf SMDS.pdf Dial_up.pdf SDLC-etc.pdf X25.pdf VPN.pdf Voice_Data.pdf wireless.pdf DSL_Dig_Subscr_Ln.pdf Cable.pdf Transparent-Bridging.pdf Mixed-Media-Bridging.pdf Source-Route-Bridging.pdf LAN-Switching.pdf atm.pdf MPLS_Tag-Switching.pdf DLSw.pdf OSI-Protocols.pdf Internet-Protocols.pdf IPv6.pdf XNS.pdf AppleTalk.pdf VINES.pdf IBM-SNA-Protocols.pdf DECnet.pdf Enhanced_IGRP.pdf IBM_SNA_routing.pdf IGRP.pdf IP-Multi.pdf NLSP.pdf OSI-Routing.pdf OSPF.pdf RIP.pdf RSVP.pdf QoS.pdf SMRP.pdf Security.pdf Dir-Enabled_Net.pdf Net_caching.pdf IBM-Net-Mgmt.pdf RMON.pdf SNMP.pdf bgp.pdf Multi-Acc.pdf Tag-Switching.pdf
```

Comment: +1 for sheer awesomeness.

Answer (score 2):

I know it might be fairly labour intensive, but you could download all the chapters and the use something like [PDF Merge 1.0](http://www.brothersoft.com/pdf-merge-25708.html) to join them all together into one.

Comment: i was hoping to avoid that, but thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find it as one, easily way to get all the chapters would be something like:

```
wget <yourlink>
while read line; do 
   echo wget http://www.cisco.com/$line; 
done < <(grep -o '/en/US/docs/internetworking/technology/handbook/.*.html' Intro-to-Internet.html | sed 's/html/pdf/')
```

I use variations on the above to get lectures sometimes, if the site is complicated I might use a perl HTML parser.  You will need to modify the above a little, didn't want to post the exact code to crawl a site.